# Maple integral will not evaluate the limit?

Tags: limit, integral, maple

Maple will not evaluate fully evaluate this integral, instead it gives the solution as a limit for r approaching infinity. How do I foce maple to actually evaluate this limit?

Here is the integral:

```
int(Z^3*Z^2*r^3*exp(-Z*r/a)/(pi*a^5), r = 0 .. infinity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result depends upon `signum(Z/a)` (ie. whether `Z/a` is greater or less than zero).

```
int(Z^3*Z^2*r^3*exp(-Z*r/a)/(Pi*a^5),
    r = 0 .. infinity) assuming Z/a>0;

      6 Z 
      ----
      Pi a

int(Z^3*Z^2*r^3*exp(-Z*r/a)/(Pi*a^5),
    r = 0 .. infinity) assuming Z/a<0;

    -infinity
```

ps. Also, I used `Pi` as the symbol for the well-known constant. The lowercase name `pi` doesn't mean anything special in Maple.